# How can I show my list items after they are hidden?

Tags: jquery

I have a list that decreases automatically and hides each item in the list after a certain amount of time, using a `for loop` and it is working perfectly. What I'm trying to do is create some code that allows me to click a button and have all my list items regenerate, but I'm having trouble doing this. Once I click the button which my Regeneration code is attached to, I don't get the expected results. It regenerates my list items, but then the decrease code stops working. Sometimes it hides only 1 item, sometimes it hides 2 but then it just completely stops. My Health Regeneration code isn't working properly. Please help me to fix this.

```
<!--THIS IS MY LIST-->
<div class="health-bar">
    <ul>
    <li class="heart5"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart4"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart3"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart2"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart1"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the health depletion code

```
function healthDeplete(){
var lis = $(".health-bar ul li");
for(var i=0; i<=lis.length; i++){
   (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     lis.eq(i).hide();
    }, i * 2000);
   })(i);
  }
};
```

This is the health regeneration code which isn't working right

```
function healthRegeneration(){
var lis = $(".health-bar ul li");
  for(var i=1; i<=lis.length; i++){
     $("#health-screen .health-bar ul li").show();
  };
};
```

Comment: $("#health-screen .health-bar ul li").show() should be:  $(".health-bar ul li").show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function healthDeplete(){
  var lis = $(".health-bar ul li");
  for(var i=0; i<=lis.length; i++){
   (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     lis.eq(i).hide();
    }, i * 2000);
   })(i);
  }
};
//------This is the health regeneration code which isn't working right----//

$('button').click(function(){
  var lis = $(".health-bar ul li");
  for(var i=0; i<=lis.length; i++){
   $(lis[i]).show();
  };
});

healthDeplete();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="health-bar">
<ul>
    <li class="heart5"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart4"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart3"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart2"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart1"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
</ul>

<button>Click ME!!!</button>
```

if you do `$("#health-screen .health-bar ul li").show();` then it will show all the `li`, then no need of looping it.

```js
function healthDeplete(){
  var lis = $(".health-bar ul li");
  for(var i=0; i<=lis.length; i++){
   (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){
     lis.eq(i).hide();
    }, i * 2000);
   })(i);
  }
};
//------This is the health regeneration code which isn't working right----//

$('button').click(function(){
  $(".health-bar ul li").slideDown();
});

healthDeplete();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="health-bar">
<ul>
    <li class="heart5"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart4"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart3"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart2"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
    <li class="heart1"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"></li>
</ul>

<button>Click ME!!!</button>
```

Hope this will help you.